# Django view: working with a file result in indentation error

Tags: python, django

trying to write in django the following view:

```
def amenity(request):
    f = open('some_file.txt', 'w+')
    f.write("text")
    f.close()
    return HttpResponse("Done")
```

result in the following error calling it from the browser

```
Exception Type: IndentationError
Exception Value: unindent does not match any outer indentation level (views.py, line 19)
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not mixing spaces and tabs?  Usually you can check with `python -tt`, but  I don't know how that would work on django...

Comment: You need to show more code than this, your problem is not evident from the code you posted. What is line 19? Did you check for tabs and spaces being mixed?

Comment: @mgilson: just fine, `python -tt manage.py`

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Good to know.  Now that I'm doing more web programming I suppose there's a chance I might need to use `django` someday...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, an `IndentationError` means there is an indentation error!

Python is indentation-sensitive. Make sure that:

1. All of your code is indented properly. Everything is in it's proper level.
2. You are not mixing spaces and tabs characters to indent. This is where people usually stuck.

Hope this helps!